# Powershell script to convert Excel sheet to txt

Tags: excel, powershell

I have an Excel file with multiple worksheets and I need to convert one specific worksheet to a txt file using Powershell. I 'borrowed' a script that does the conversion, but it does not specify which sheet so it just does the first one.

```
$FolderLoc = "D:\Information Services\Data\"
$files = Get-ChildItem $FolderLoc\*.xlsx -recurse

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $false
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

ForEach ($file in $files) {
     Write "Loading File '$($file.Name)'..."
     $WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($file.Fullname)
     $NewFilePath = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($file.Fullname,".txt")
     $Workbook.SaveAs($NewFilepath, 42)   # xlUnicodeText
}

# cleanup
$Excel.Quit()
```

The specific sheet I need to convert is called 'All Detail'. I made various attempts at inserting a line to identify the worksheet, but none have worked.

```
$FolderLoc = "D:\Information Services\Data"
$files = Get-ChildItem $FolderLoc\*.xlsx -recurse

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $false
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

ForEach ($file in $files) {
     Write "Loading File '$($file.Name)'..."
     $WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($file.Fullname)
     **$worksheet = "All Detail"**
     $NewFilePath = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($file.Fullname,".txt")
     $Workbook.SaveAs($NewFilepath, 42)   # xlUnicodeText
}

# cleanup
$Excel.Quit()
```

Comment: Try `$Workbook.Worksheets.Item('All Detail').Activate()` before the SaveAs

Comment: That worked. Thank you.